# Excel Interop Control Panel UI Elements Don't appear

Tags: excel, com, add-in

I created a document level addin to programatically create excel charts.  I would like the user to be able to save the file as a different name , reopen the excel file at a later time and be able to manipulate the data using the UI controls I created in the control panel that I added to the document.  Everything great when the user loads from the published source (UI controls appear as expected.... but when I load the excel file the second time, The "Document Actions" pane appears but none of my  UI controls are present.

What am I missing or forgetting to do ?